# How to view Chrome browsing history on ipad?

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, browser-history

There is no item 'History' in 'Chrome menu' as suggested here:

http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=95589

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new iPad version of Chrome has this feature where you can type chrome://history into the search field / address bar to retrieve history.

Currently the iOS version of Google Chrome is 28.0.1500.16 so presumably older versions of the app do not have any way to get history, but newer versions do.

Comment: Yes, indeed so.

Answer (score 0):

If you type direct into the web address box in iOS chrome some words relevant to the item in the history, then the page should appear in the drop-down list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome on iOS there doesn't seem to be a global history section as there is when using Chrome on your Mac.

On a Mac you would press the "hotdog" menu button and simply select history.

On iOS the only method I have seen for browsing history is holding the back button down for a couple seconds in each tab. Holding this button own will then give you a list of the most recently visited pages for this particular tab.

There is the option of deleting browsing history, but as yet there is no option to view it.